# How to run Python scripts in cmd using sublime build system (Sublime Text)?

Tags: python, cmd, sublimetext3, build-system

I'm trying to run `python scripts` through the sublime build system (Sublime Text). I want built to start terminal, execute the program and wait till press any keys.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "start cmd.exe @cmd /c python -u \"$file\" && echo. && pause",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": "true"
}
```

The above code executes but it terminates as soon as it completes even though `pause` is added. Using `/k` terminal stays on screen but then we have manually close it instead of pressing any key.

How to configure shell script so that it will run the code in terminal and end when a key is pressed.

Comment: Why are you opening a cmd instance from another cmd instance inside a cmd shell? Why not just `"@start python -u \"$file\" & echo. & pause"`.

Comment: @Compo sublime build system doesn't allow to take input just output. Also, I don't want to use files for inputs. I want to take user input so, I'm opening cmd. `shell_cmd` is opening cmd just cmd instance.

BTW I tried your command still pausing.

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means in relation to my comment. Your question stated that it was not pausing, despite you having used the `pause` command, your comment above is complaining that it is pausing. Now unless I'm incapable of understanding the basic mechanics of this task, it seems to me as if it has worked. Please try to properly explain the task you're trying to perform, what exactly is happening when you perform it, what exactly you'd like to happen instead, why you're complaining about not wanting to use a file, when you posted a command using a file, how user input is relevant

Comment: @Compo, sorry for me not being clear. Sublime Text provides build systems to allow users to run external programs. Examples of common uses for build systems include: compiling, transpiling, linting, and executing tests. Build systems are specified via JSON and saved in a file with the extension .sublime-build. The following is a basic example of a build system. This build system will execute the currently open Python file. `"cmd": ["python", "$file"]`. The executed output will be shown at bottom of Sublime; if there is an input in a python file, we can't take it through this build system.

Comment: If `"cmd": ["python", "$file"]` executes the python file in cmd, then why are you using `"shell_cmd": "start cmd.exe @cmd /c python -u \"$file\""`. When you use `"cmd":` or `"shell_cmd":` that opens the shell, i.e. `cmd.exe`. So once that is open you are using a built-in `cmd.exe` command, `start` to start a second `cmd.exe` session passing it  the arguments `@cmd /c python -u "$file"`. So the third cmd.exe command is invoked and is passed the following arguments, `python -u "$file`. Do you see what I mean now? you appear to be running three `cmd.exe` instances, just to run a `python` script!

Comment: So what I was doing like, start `cmd`,  execute the python file, and wait for key to hit. Earlier I had created build system for `cpp`. `"cmd": ["g++", "-Wall", "${file}", "-std=c++17", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "&&", "start", "cmd.exe", "@cmd", "/c", "${file_path}/${file_base_name} && echo. && pause"]`. It takes input, and after execution waits till hit any key. Now I'm trying to do same for python. Python build system, I've created , executes program but doesn't `pause` after execution. DOC [link](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html#options)

Comment: `cmd.exe` open by build system is not taking any STDIN input. For that matter I was opening new `cmd.exe` instance. It worked for me for cpp.

Comment: But you're opening two more `cmd.exe` instances, not just one!

Answer (score 1):

python -i works fine.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "start cmd.exe /c python -i \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": "true"
}
```